# How to bind form fields to model if property names are different?

Tags: forms, playframework-2.0, model-binding, playframework-2.1

I am using Play Framework 2.1

I have POST request coming from external system and trying to bind it to my model, but names of model properties are different from parameter names in request: request has "body-plain" and model has "bodyPlain" etc. How can I indicate mapping from form names to model properties' names?

I'm trying to bind model like this:

```
Form<MailGunMessageData> mgDataForm = form(MailGunMessageData.class);
MailGunMessageData mgData = mgDataForm.bindFromRequest().get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind to your everytime, you can also just use `DynamicForm` and then bind only selected fields from any data:

```
DynamicForm df = form().bindFromRequest();
MailGunMessageData mgData = new MailGunMessageData();

mgData.mail = df.get("email-address");
```

Comment: I did like you suggested. I hoped there's more elegant solution, like passing in map of name-name or giving some annotations to model fields etc.

Comment: Well you would need to fill the map as well, so instead maybe just create a constructor in your model and pass whole DynamicForm to it. It will be useful if you are gonna to use this binding in several places

Comment: I think custom constructor like that would introduce unjustified dependency between my model and Play